# java: check if string contains any of a letter from g-z

Tags: java, string

I want to check whether if any part of the string contains a letter from the range [g-zG-Z].

Take for example the string "aged01", it contains a g, it should print out 
"Error:String contains a letter from g-zG-Z" but instead it's printing out the string. please help

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "aged01";
    if(s.contains("[g-zG-Z]+")) {
        System.out.println("Error:String contains a letter from g-zG-Z");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use `string.matches`  method or `Pattern` ,`Matcher` classes instead of `string.contains` because `contains` method won't accept a regex as an argument.

```
String s = "aged01";
if(s.matches(".*[g-zG-Z].*")) {
    System.out.println("Error:String contains a letter from g-zG-Z");
}
else {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output:

```
Error:String contains a letter from g-zG-Z
```

Comment: i think it's because `contains` method won't accept a regex as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

`contains(substring)` check for actual substring, it doesn't allow a regex in it which you are doing. Check it with `matches`

```
String s = "aged01"; 
if(s.matches(".*[g-zG-Z].*")) { 
    System.out.println("Error:String contains a letter from g-zG-Z"); 
} else { 
    System.out.println(s); 
}
```

Here `.*` allows multiple occurrence of other characters.

Comment: can you format your answer so that we can read your source more easily and upvote your answer.